# LINQ and unique IDs

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I have written some LINQ where I check against a database whether or not the username is unique when I am adding a new user.  My code (see below) works, but is there a better way to do this?  I am currently relying on trapping an error if the username does not exist.

```
try
        {
            var User = (from u in _database.Users
                        where u.UserID == strUserName
                        select u).First();

            if (User != null)
            {
                blnUnique = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            blnUnique = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Enumerable.Any<TSource>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) extension method:

```
bool isUnique = (from u in database.Users
                 where u.UserID == userName
                 select u).Any();
```

Here's an alternative way of expressing this using a [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

```
bool isUnique = database.Users.Any(u => u.UserID == userName);
```

Note that the [equals operator on the String class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx) will make a case-sensitive ordinal comparison. If you wish to make a case-insensitive comparison you'll have to use the [String.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) method:

```
bool isUnique = database.Users.Any(
    u => u.UserID.Equals(userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Thanks...'Any' looks to be what I was looking for as it returns a true or false unlike FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 1):

Use FirstOrDefault() instead of First()

Answer (score 0):

Is _database a repository? If so, I would suggest implementing a dictionary internally so you can expose a

```
FindUser(userID)
```

method which returns null if userID is not found. Your loop won't scale well.